# Detect bundler installed groups

Tags: ruby, bundler, rakefile

We're using bundler, and on deploy server application is installed without some gems

```
bundler install --without test
```

In this case some code should be deactivated (like loading rspec && cucumber task into Rakefile)

Is there some simple methods like `Bundler.installed?(:test)` то detect this case?

Answer (score 1):

What you are basically trying to do is distinguishing your `production` environment from your `development` (or `test`) environment. You should not rely on the installed gems for this, but Bundler groups can still be useful.

I would recommend using an environment variable, for example like in Rails. Then you could set this var in your server config with

```
$ export MYAPP_ENV='production'
```

and load it into your application with the default value `:test`:

```
MYAPP_ENV = ENV['MYAPP_ENV'].to_sym || :test
```

This way, you can always tell if you are on the production server. Suppose your Gemfile looks something like this:

```
source :rubygems

gem "sinatra"

group :test do
  gem "rspec"
  gem "faker"
end
```

You can then require only the relevant gems with

```
Bundler.require(MYAPP_ENV)
```

Back to your original question: Now it is very easy to check if you are on your production machine or not, by simply using `MYAPP_ENV` again:

```
if MYAPP_ENV == :test
  # do some test specific stuff
end
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, solution is clear, but we have a bunch of environments, sometimes changing, and I would prefer not to depend on it. Anyway thanks :)